# recast of a dataset. I cant reshape my data set. the r code was running yesterday but not today whats the problem behind?

Tags: r

I dont know whats my problem in R, but i ve to say that I m a beginnerr
In a nutshell i have to reshape the data set.
Yesterday everything was ok, but today I cant run the whole R code again-.- dont know what to do.

```
library(reshape)
library(AER)
library(foreign)  
library(stargazer)  
library(nlme)
library(texreg)
library(readr)
library(dummies)
library(stargazer)
library(car)
library(sandwich)
library(readr)
BCHHS_data <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lachlandeer/moec415_data_archive/master/ps01/BCHHS_data.csv")
BCHHS<-BCHHS_data
BCHHS$lnearn <- log(BCHHS$earning)
BCHHS$agesq <- BCHHS$age^2

#reshape the dataset
library(reshape)
BCHHS2 <- recast(BCHHS, family~variable+twinno, id.var = c("family", "twinno"))
```

this recast function doesnt work at all... it says i d use different names but they are quite the same i guess:(

do you have a solution? if i wasnt clear enough please let me know

Comment: If something ran before and doesn't now, usually there is something with the environment causing the problem. A possibility is that you had another package loaded after `reshape` that was actually active without you realizing it. Maybe try `library(reshape2)`? Just a thought.

Comment: you re my man.... it is running now... reshape2 was the problem at all sry for waisting your time